# How do I run docker-compose up without getting build error

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to run:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get the error:

```
Command "/usr/local/bin/python    
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-    
packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py     
get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpefh9j7q8" failed with   
error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-iv15vhai/peewee
59.18 You are using pip version 19.0.1, however version  
21.3.1 is available.
59.18 You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --
upgrade pip' command.

------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r    
requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code:  
1
```

I have upgraded pip and still get the error. I tried updating the dockerfile. Here is the current code in the Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.6

# Set the working directory to /src
WORKDIR /src

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /src
COPY requirements.txt /src/

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt 
RUN apk update && \
apk add --no-cache ffmpeg make automake gcc g++ subversion     
&& \
apk add --no-cache sqlite-dev && \
apk add --no-cache libffi-dev openssl-dev && \
pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` doesn't seem to be formatted correctly. That `/src` before the `COPY` line is wrong. If this was just an issue posting here, please [edit] your question to correct it

Comment: The /src was originally part of the commented out line.

Comment: Do the pip upgrade before installing from requirements.txt, not after.

Comment: I just did so, but I get the same error

Comment: It would be nice to see your requirements.txt file as well to reproduce your issue.